# return moment.js function in days number only without strings

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

So, I'm using moment.js to calculate number of days between the current date and a given date and it returns something like "a month ago" or "5 days ago". I want it to just return "30" or "5" instead.

```
import moment from "moment";


console.log(moment("2018-09-01", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow())
```

Comment: Moment docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.

```
console.log(moment().diff(moment("2018-09-01"), "days"))
```